# Exact Matching text with dataframe column in r

Tags: r, exact-match

I have a vector of words in R:

> `words = c("Awesome","Loss","Good","Bad")`

And I have the following dataframe in R:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                 Response = c("Today is an awesome day", 
                              "Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good",
                              "I have losses today"))
```

What I want to do is words that are exact matching in Response column should be extracted and inserted into new column in dataframe. Final output should look like this

```
ID           Response                        Match          
1            Today is an awesome day        Awesome           
2            Yesterday was a bad day        Bad,Good           
             ,but today it is good      
3            I have losses today            NA
```

I used the following code:

### extract the list of matching words

```
x <- sapply(words, function(x) grepl(tolower(x), tolower(df$Response)))
```

### paste the matching words together

```
df$Words <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i], collapse = ","))
```

But it is providing the match, but not the exact. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use anchors in your `words` vector, you will ensure exact matches: ^ asserts that you're at the start, $ that you're at the end of a word. So:

```
words = c("Awesome","^Loss$","Good","Bad")
```

Then use your code:

```
x <- sapply(words, function(x) grepl(tolower(x), tolower(df$Response)))
df$Words <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i], collapse = ","))
```

which gives:

```
> df
  ID                                     Response    Words
1  1                      Today is an awesome day  Awesome
2  2 Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good Good,Bad
3  3                          I have losses today
```

To turn blanks to `NA`:

```
df$Words[df$Words == ""] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(Words = map_chr(str_extract_all(Response, str_c("
       (?i)\\b(", str_c(words, collapse="|"), ")\\b")), toString))
#   ID                                     Response     Words
#1  1                      Today is an awesome day   awesome
#2  2 Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good bad, good
#3  3                          I have losses today
```

#### data

```
words <- c("Awesome","Loss","Good","Bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first `*apply` function to a two lines function. If the regex becomes `"\\bword\\b"` then it captures the word surrounded by boundaries.

```
x <- sapply(words, function(x) {
  y <- paste0("\\b", x, "\\b")
  grepl(tolower(y), tolower(df$Response))
})
```

Now run the second `apply` as posted in the question.

```
df$Words <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i], collapse = ","))

df
#  ID                                     Response    Words
#1  1                      Today is an awesome day  Awesome
#2  2 Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good Good,Bad
#3  3                          I have losses today
```

As for the `NA`'s, I will use function `is.na<-`.

```
is.na(df$Words) <- df$Words == ""
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID           Response
1            'Today is an awesome day'
2            'Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good'
3            'I have losses today'
", header = TRUE)

words <- c("Awesome","Loss","Good","Bad")
```