# How to tabularize a text output with new lines into a dataframe?

Tags: r, regex

This is the structure of the blob of text that I'm working with:

```
reprEx <- "] WITHDRAWALS\nDATE DESCRIPTION AMOUNT\n04/01 Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mike T 819018100 $1,450.00\n04/01 Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mandy Doid 809012906 2,665.00"
```

I would like to be able to take the text on every new line and separate each element in the line to a respective dataframe column. For example I need the date on each line to be in a DATE column, the description of the transaction to be in a DESCRIPTION column, and the number before the end of the line to be put into the AMOUNT column. This is an example of my desired output in a dataframe.

```
desiredResult <- data.frame(DATE = c("04/01", "04/01"),
                            DESCRIPTION = c("Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mike T 819018100", "Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mandy Doid 819012906"),
                            AMOUNT = c("$1,450.00", "2,665.00"))
```

Comment: you'll probably want a column for the `8090128100`, `8090129906`, which are possibly transaction IDs, though more likely times. Why is this a blob as it looks like it came from a table.

Comment: yea it did come from a table. I used tesseract to parse text from a picture of a bank statement. I am trying to tabularize the tesseract output in the format of the table

Comment: real or fake is immaterial to solving the problem, [an approach more broadly applicable to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160426/exact-matching-text-with-dataframe-column-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this for a start?
This solution uses `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package:

```
desiredResult <- data.frame(
  DATE = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "\\d{2}/\\d{2}")),
  DESCRIPTION = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "(?<=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\\s)[\\s\\w$]+(?=\\d{1,3},\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})")),
  AMOUNT = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "\\d{1,3},\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}"))
)
```

Output:

```
desiredResult
   DATE                                           DESCRIPTION   AMOUNT
1 04/01    Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mike T 8090128100 $ 1,450.00
2 04/01 Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mandy Dold 8090129906  2,665.00
```

If you want to get rid of the dollar sign in column `DESCRIPTION`, you can do this:

```
desiredResult <- data.frame(
  DATE = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}")),
  DESCRIPTION = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "(?<=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\\s)[\\s\\w]+(?=\\d{1,3},\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})|(?<=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\\s)[\\s\\w]+(?=\\$\\d{1,3},\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})")),
  AMOUNT = unlist(str_extract_all(reprEx, "\\d{1,3},\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}"))
)
```

Output:

```
desiredResult
   DATE                                           DESCRIPTION   AMOUNT
1 04/01     Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mike T 8090128100  1,450.00
2 04/01 Quickpay With Zelle Payment To Mandy Dold 8090129906  2,665.00
```

Comment: @gizaom Hi, I've edited the code to approximate your desired result more closely

Comment: And to pull out the ID/time value to its own column? well, there's enough meat here to play with that.

Comment: What do you mean? Which values are the ID/time values?